# How to make a 2D draggable navigation effect without using plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a draggable navigation slider similar to  [weired christmas](http://christmas.rogue.studio/).
How to see the slider:-

- Go to http://christmas.rogue.studio/
- Click on the "Send a Christmas card" button
- Click on any image to open the popup and the slider is inside the popup.

Currently, in my implementation, whenever I'm clicking on any image the popup is appearing but my 1st image is on the top because of the highest `z-index`. What I actually want is whenever users click on any image that particular image should come with the highest z-index and the rest of the other images will follow the z-index according to that particular image z-index like in the example website ( http://christmas.rogue.studio/ ).

Moreover, I am stuck with the previous button concept: whenever I am clicking on the previous button it is adding a class of animate-out but setting zindex function is not working properly. The next button functionality is working fine. special thanks to *Reyno* I got help from him for the next button functionality.

Here is the working example https://codepen.io/mukul6996/pen/bGeEZaR

Below is my code.

> index.html file

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-row">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602642753381-030eacbf4a58?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2434&q=80" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602609741544-de5fc39b88ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602608646744-6a03235141c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2434&q=80" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602607878796-baf56d8dfc8a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="item-link">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602653077972-0a5a38f9a466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2458&q=80" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Gallery Popup -->
    <div class="gallery-popup">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-link">x</a>
        <div class="collection">
            <div class="post">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602642753381-030eacbf4a58?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2434&q=80" />
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602609741544-de5fc39b88ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602608646744-6a03235141c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2434&q=80" />
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602607878796-baf56d8dfc8a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80" />
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602653077972-0a5a38f9a466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2458&q=80" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-holder">
            <button class="prev-btn">Previous</button>
            <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Gallery Popup -->
</div>
```

> style.css file

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
    
    .gallery-popup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .collection {
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        perspective: 1500px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 120px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .post {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        background: orangered;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 4rem;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.09, 0.105, 1.005);
    }
    
    .post img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .animate {
        transform: translate3d(350px, 25px, -400px);
    }
    
    .animate-out {
        transform: translate3d(350px, 15px, -100px);
    }
    
    .button-holder {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .button-holder button {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: none;
        background: orangered;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    .close-link {
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 15px;
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        background: orangered;
    }
    
    .gallery-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
    
    .gallery-row .item {
        padding: 10px;
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
    
    .gallery-row .item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

> main.js file

```
$(function() {

        var galleryWrapper = $('.gallery-wrapper');

        galleryWrapper.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                galleryPopup = $this.find('.gallery-popup'),
                prevBtn = $this.find('.prev-btn'),
                nextBtn = $this.find('.next-btn'),
                posts = $this.find('.post'),
                current = 0


            // -------- Opening popup by clicking on any item-link
            // --------------------------------------------

            $this.find('.item-link').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                galleryPopup.fadeIn();
                $('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            });

            // -------- Closing popup by clicking on close-link
            // --------------------------------------------

            $this.find('.close-link').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                galleryPopup.fadeOut();
                $('body, html').css('overflow', 'initial');
            })

            // -------- Popup slider script
            // --------------------------------------------

            function setZIndex() {
                for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                    const post = posts[i];
                    const {
                        zIndex
                    } = post.style;

                    post.style.zIndex = zIndex ? (Number(zIndex) + 1) % posts.length : posts.length - i - 1;
                }
            }

            nextBtn.on('click', function() {
                const post = posts[current];
                post.classList.add('animate');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    post.classList.remove('animate');
                    setZIndex();
                }, 300);

                current = (current + 1) % posts.length;
            });

            prevBtn.on('click', function() {
                const post = posts[current];
                post.classList.add('animate-out');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    post.classList.remove('animate-out');
                    setZIndex();
                }, 300);

                current = (current - 1) % posts.length;
            });

            setZIndex();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Mukul, what have you tried to reproduce the look and feel (you should post your code)?  Have you pulled the CSS and JavaScript from the site? You really need to put together a question that meets the [minimum quality standard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some CSS to create 3D transition. All you then need to do is set the correct z-index and timing to create the better looking animation.

This is just a small concept i had lying around but it shows you how to achieve this effect.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const posts = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
let current = 0;

const setZIndex = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    const post = posts[i];
    const { zIndex } = post.style;
    
    post.style.zIndex = zIndex ? (Number(zIndex) + 1) % posts.length : posts.length - i - 1;
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const post = posts[current];
    post.classList.add("animate");
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      post.classList.remove("animate");
      setZIndex();
    }, 500);
    
    current = (current + 1) % posts.length;
});

setZIndex();
```

```css
.collection {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.post {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orangered;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.09, 0.105, 1.005);
}

.animate {
  transform: translate3d(300px, -25px, 500px);
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="post">1</div>
  <div class="post">2</div>
  <div class="post">3</div>
  <div class="post">4</div>
  <div class="post">5</div>
</div>

<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Reyno for your help but I'm stuck with the logic of previous button. It is adding the animate class but not adding the zIndex with the previous functionality.